# implement random 0 1 with custom parameter

Tags: algorithm, probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I have a function which generates either 0 or 1 with equal probability = *0.5* and I want to implement another function using the previous one and basic mathematical manipulations that does the same thing but with given probability *p* (*0<=p<=1*)

This is not my homework or smth, I just came across it and would really appreciate any hints!

Comment: What basic mathematical manipulations are allowed? Anything you can do in C without calling libraries? Or only +, -, * and /?

Comment: @Patrick87 well it is stated "basic mathematical operations", I guess using <random> would be illegal

Comment: But can we save values in variables, do if/then/else, loop, etc.?

Comment: I would say yes, almost every algorithm includes these

Comment: One last question - is *p* a rational number or just any real number? In the latter case, are you looking for an algorithm that gives the exact real probability or would a close rational approximation suffice?

Comment: Let it be int random(double p)? Shall be fine? Again, I cannot be sure about everything, I guees I am supposed to design algorithm for p in [0;1] segment. But if it is rational, using m/n representation of p is not okay, imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually roughly the same algorithm as Patrick87 proposes, but it generates the bits one at a time and stops immediately when it finds an answer. It's essentially related to [arithmetic encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).

I've implemented here in Python.

```py
>>> # Create a function which returns 0 or 1 with equal probability.
>>> from random import random
>>> f = lambda: int(random()<0.5)

>>> # Check
>>> sum(f() for i in range(1000000))
500251
>>> # Use that to create a biased function. You can use this
>>> # either with a rational number expressed as numerator, denominator
>>> # or with a value of p between 0 and 1. Python doesn't care whether
>>> # numbers are integers but other languages might.
>>> def biased(numer, denom = 1):
...    while True:
...      numer += numer
...      if numer >= denom:
...        numer -= denom
...        if f(): return 1
...      else:
...        if f(): return 0
... 
>>> sum(biased(0,19) for i in range(1900000))
0
>>> sum(biased(1,19) for i in range(1900000))
100096
>>> sum(biased(5,19) for i in range(1900000))
500255
>>> sum(biased(18,19) for i in range(1900000))
1799988
>>> sum(biased(19,19) for i in range(1900000))
1900000
```

In effect, the loop constructs the binary representation of numerator/denominator one bit at a time by doubling the current value of numerator and comparing with denominator. It then compares that with a lazily generated random binary fraction until it can determine whether the random fraction is greater or less.

Although the number of calls to the base function `f` is theoretically unbounded, the expected number of times `biased` calls `f` is 2, regardless of the arguments to biased. (That's because the probability that a random stream of bits will match `k` binary digits is 2<sup>-k</sup> independent of the actual values of the binary digits.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which should be feasible in many cases is described as follows:

1. Interpret *p* as a rational number *a / b* in lowest terms. If *p* is just a floating point number between 0 and 1, then *b* is just a power of 10 with as many zeroes as places after the decimal, and *a* is the number formed by taking the digit string after the decimal and eliminating leading zeroes.
2. Generate a random bit string of length *ceiling(log(b - 1))* where the base of the logarithm is 2 and *ceiling* rounds any non-integer number up to the next integer. Do this by calling the provided function and recording the answers.
3. If the random bit string, excluding leading zeroes, represents an integer between 0 and *b - 1*, inclusive, then continue; otherwise, if the number is greater than *b*, return to step 2, generating random bit strings until you get one that works.
4. If the random bit string, excluding leading zeroes, represents an integer between 0 and *a - 1*, inclusive, then return 0; otherwise return 1.

This should return in finite expected time, but unbounded worst-case time, the number 0 with probability *p = a / b* and the number 1 with probability *p = (b - a) / b*, exactly, given that *p* is a rational number (note that doubles are all rational as described in step 1).